# Get user_metadata Roles in Auth0

Tags: auth0

I am trying to get user Roles when after logged in in Auth0, as per documentation, I created a rule

```
function (user, context, callback) {
    var namespace = 'https://myayth0.com/';
    context.idToken[namespace + 'app_metadata'] = user.app_metadata;
    context.idToken[namespace + 'user_metadata'] = user.user_metadata;
    context.idToken[namespace + 'roles'] = user.user_metadata.roles;
    context.accessToken[namespace + 'app_metadata'] = user.app_metadata;
    context.accessToken[namespace + 'user_metadata'] = user.user_metadata;
    context.accessToken[namespace + 'roles'] = user.user_metadata.roles;
    callback(null, user, context);
 }
```

Now I have this data return

```
(...)
 email_verified
:
(...)
 https://ian:auth0:com/app_metadata
 :
(...)
https://ian:auth0:com/roles
:
https://ian:auth0:com/user_metadata
(...)
:
(...)
picture
:
(...)
sub
:
(...)
updated_at
:
(...)
```

Now accessing picture or email  is easy

```
     this.user.email, this.user.picture
```

But how about the role?

```
   https://ian:auth0:com/roles
     : Array(1)
     0: "admin"
   ..................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this [Auth0 Community Answer](https://community.auth0.com/questions/8295/read-custom-claims-in-angular).

Once added to your token and returned to your Client application, it should simply be a case of validating and decoding the token to retrieve the value from the namespaced custom claim key.

You should also check whether it makes sense to have the ROLES information tagged to `app_metadata` rather than `user_metadata` (which is modifiable by end user) - and whether it is an `ID Token` (consumer app) or `Access Token` (receiving API) that should be responsible for holding the custom claim.

Answer (score 1):

```
const roles = this.user['https://ian:auth0:com/roles']
              this.roles = roles[0]
```

Comment: Please see my answer above. if you are asking how to reference a javascript object by key then ok...